# How to open tcpdf document in a new browser tab?

Tags: yii

Currently my pdf generated and shows in the same browser tab,so i need this in  a new tab
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```